# How to convert list of binary strings to decimals in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, integer

I want to convert the following list of binaries into decimals:
I have:

```
a=['0010', '0010', '0100', '1000'] #list of string
```

I would like to have:

```
a=[2,2,4,8] #list of ints to insert them into another algorithm.
```

Comment: Alternatively: `[int(s, base=2) for s in a]`. Maybe worth glancing at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: Note that you don't want them in decimal. You just want integers. Numbers don't have base. Representations of number do. "0010" is a binary string representing number 2. "2" is a decimal string, representing number 2. But 2 is just a number. You choose a base, only to print or to input those numbers (including in code, and even in this comment, which leads to me saying "2 has no basis", while using base 10 to say it). When you write in code ``x=12``, sure your code use base 10 to decide the value of x. But once it has been stored in x, it has no base anymore. It is just a number.

Comment: One could claim that x is in binary, because it is stored in computer memory in binary. But that is just an implementation problem. If python was implemented on a ternary computer, it would be transparent, and still the same number. But whatever, x in not at all a decimal. Just a number. Whose value happens to have been specified by a decimal code, but there is no way to tell from x.

Answer (score 1):

```
def binToDec(n): 
    return int (n,2)
#Simple function for conversion of binary to decimal

if __name__ == '__main__':
a=['0010','0100','1000']
b=[] #empty list to store decimal as int

#Loop through list a and send values to function then copy it to other array

for x in range(len(a)):
     b.append(binToDec(a[x]))
     print(b)
```